# mmenu.js set Selected not work with detect url

Tags: javascript, mmenu

we are integrating mmenu on our site, the selected addon set so configured does not seem to work.

```
    <!-- NAV mmenu scripts -->
<script src="../../res/mmenu/dist/mmenu.js"></script>
<script>
    const menu = new Mmenu(
    document.querySelector("#menu"),
    {
        slidingSubmenus: true,
        theme: "light",
        setSelected: {
            current: "detect",
            hover: true,
            parent: true,
        },
        counters: {
            add: false,
        },
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what is not working? What is the expected outcome, what is the actual outcome?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: current: "detect" not work and it does not add the selected class to the corresponding <li> element